# searching for specific keys in multiple independent hashMap objects

Tags: java, hashmap, key

I have a slightly theoretical question that I want to clear up before I start programing my solution any further...

Background.
I need to perform comparisons between 2 (or possible more) MS Access files.

Each file should contain data that is found in one of the others.

Due to the 'limitation' I have encountered with JDBC and connecting to Access result sets (they are only forward scrollable!) I have created 'java objects' (classes) that models the structure of a result set.

in essence
I have an object that models a single record line in the result set (lets call it a rowSet)
A resSet object then has an 'array' of rowSets.

However to 'speed things up' I catch the values in the key and index columns and create a hashMap of 'key_Index' this to the relevant rowSet object.

Me comparison then does the following.

take the first resSet object (to use as the master), from this collect the individual the Key_Index hashmaps (lets call it 'aKey'....

Now use this 'aKey' object to search into the other avalailable resSet objects and see if any contain a value of a key_Index that matches the values in 'aKey'.

However I have just had a rather annoying thought.

If I use the code
    resSet.get(aKey)
on one of my other resSet objects will I have problems as the 'aKey' object is obviously not the same object - although it's contents should be the same (ie comparable).

I have to say that as I read my question I think it is not well worded... so I think I will include a copy of the class that I have created...

The important parts:

members:
challenge - an arrayList of 'result set' type objects.

method:
the runChallenge()

```
package KWhite;

/**
 * the RScomparator is designed for the instance of comparing a double entry database system, as
 * often occurs in localy run medical trials data.
 * 
 * The double entry is to ensure that there are no errors made during input, the entry is performed
 * in separate independant instances. The RScolmparator object is specifically able to take any
 * number of result sets as its input (ie queries from multiple independantly created databases)
 * 
 * It should be recognised that this object should probably be called as part of a DBcomparator
 * object.
 * 
 */
//imports here

//import of logger class and required dependencies...
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

import MrBlue.DB_Table;
import TawuaiLogger.tawuaiLogger;

public class RScomparator {

//Static variables

//the logger instance
private static final TawuaiLogger.tawuaiLogger errLog = new tawuaiLogger("RScomparator");

//class member variables

/** this is a selection of ResSet objects that are going to have thier data challenged */
private ArrayList<ResSet_KW> challenge;
/**the name of the current table being challenged*/
private String tableName;
/**a 'table' object for meta data reference purposes, this can be used for getting column types etc */
private DB_Table table;

//These are our report objects
/**a report array for challenge failures */
private ArrayList<report_KW> fail;
/**a report array for errors, ie no challenger able to be made, no equivalent value found */
private ArrayList<report_KW> errors;
/**a report array for the good values */
private ArrayList<report_KW> success;

/** this is either the main class or the constructor
 * 
 * If it is a constructor rename to reflect the name of the class
 * @param args
 */
public RScomparator(DB_Table t) //TODO add arguments as required
{
    PropertyConfigurator.configure("Log4j.properties");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    challenge = new ArrayList<ResSet_KW>();
    //initialise our report objects for this challenge scenario
    fail =  new ArrayList<report_KW>();
    errors = new ArrayList<report_KW>();
    success = new ArrayList<report_KW>();
    table = t;
    tableName = t.getTblName();
}

//class methods go here

/**
 * add a result set object into this comparator
 * 
 * @param r the result set object being inserted into this challenge.
 * 
 */
public void addChallenger(ResSet_KW r)
{
this.challenge.add(r);  
}


/**
 * this runs the comparison process...
 * Although no details in of itself are returned it calls other methods that do return a value
 *
 */

public void runChallenge()
{
//TODO finish this method, creating a report object on the way

    //these are the 2 result set objects that will be compared
    ResSet_KW gold = new ResSet_KW  ();
    ResSet_KW silver = new ResSet_KW ();



    //ensure the challenger list has objects in it.
    if(challenge.size() < 2)
    {
        //it must have 2 objects..
        errLog.add(3, "there are no results available for comparison of table " + this.tableName);
        //either way we should create report object.
        this.errors.add( new report_KW(tableName));
        //break out of the method.
        return;
    }

    //get the first row of data

    gold = challenge.get(0);//the first result set.

    //for each column in the result set, perform a search for the same key in the others..
    for(HashMap<String, String> c : gold.getRS().keySet())
    {//c is the key value in the map
        //cycle over the challenge object
        for (int i=1; i<challenge.size(); i++)//we don't want to use the first element, so start from 1 not zero
        {
            silver = challenge.get(i);
            if (silver.hasKey(c))
            {
                //a temp object for meta data referencing

                //only get the actual result values if there is a match
                Column_KW a = gold.getRS().get(c);
                Column_KW b = silver.getRS().get(c);
                //make the comparison
                a.compareTo(b, this.table);
                //get the reports from the comparison
                for(report_KW k :a.getFailure())
                    {
                    this.fail.add(k);
                    }
                for(report_KW k :a.getPassed())
                {
                    this.success.add(k);
                }
                for(report_KW k :a.getPassed())
                {
                this.errors.add(k);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;//return to the next item in the for loop
            }
        }
    }









}


/**
 *a helper method to create the error message creator
 *@ param m the extra message if any, 
 *@return s the full message
 */
private String getErrMessage(String m) {
    //the third element in the current stact trace should be the calling method
    StackTraceElement caller = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[3];
    String s = m + "\ncalled from line " + caller.getLineNumber()
            + "\nmethod: " + this.getClass() + "." + caller.getMethodName();
        return s;
    }
}//end class
```

ps. any coments on my code or more that welcome

Thanks in advance

David

edit:
I just found this question, [Nested Maps or combined keys in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167543/nested-maps-or-combined-keys-in-java) is this going to be my solution, create a'custom' key_Index object and then define a hashcode() and equals object for it. However I am allready using a 'hashMap' for my key_index object, so does this perform this automatically somewhere that I haven' noticed?

Comment: Is it possible to shorten your question?  That is alot to read for what is likely to be a simple answer.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Agreed, but when I tried to shorten it I felt I wasn't explaining properly. Also I've included the code as a 'just in case it helps' type addition. As i half expect someone to ask for it anyhow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said :

> If I use the code resSet.get(aKey) on one of my other resSet objects
>   will I have problems as the 'aKey' object is obviously not the same
>   object - **although it's contents should be the same** (ie comparable).

You have to implement `equals()` and `hashcode()` respectively. It is not enough to implement `equals()`, `hashcode()` must be the same if the objects are equal.

Example:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class A {
    String name;
    Integer number;

    public A(String name, Integer number) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
    }

}

class B {
    String name;
    Integer number;

    public B(String name, Integer number) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof B) {
        return obj == this || (name.equals(((B) obj).name) && number.equals(((B) obj).number));
    }
    return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
    return name.hashCode() + number.hashCode();
    }
}

public class TestHashMap {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        A a1 = new A("a", 1);
        A anotherA1 = new A("a", 1);

        Map<A, String> as = new HashMap<A, String>();

        as.put(a1, "a1");

        System.out.println(as.get(anotherA1)); // prints null

        B b1 = new B("b", 1);
        B anotherB1 = new B("b", 1);

        Map<B, String> bs = new HashMap<B, String>();

        bs.put(b1, "b1");

        System.out.println(bs.get(anotherB1)); // prints b1

    }

}
```

Comment: See my edit, I'm using a hashMap<String,String>, my reading is telling me I may need to use a tree map in stead, or create a special object 'key_index' and have it implement the equals and hashcode methods, which is going to be better?

Comment: You can use the TreeMap but you have to provide a comparator or implement Comparable. It is another alternative if you don't want to implement equals and hashcode.

Comment: I've just had another look at the docs, and HashMap inherits an equals and hashcode method from its parent AbstractMap, I guess as I am going to be OK in this case (although there is always the possiblity that the key values have been entered in differently between DB's!)

Comment: You have to implement `hashcode()` and `equals()` in the class which is being used has key in the Map.

Comment: cool, what a star. thanks for that example. The smaller question still stands however, as my key value is in fact an object of HashMap<String,String> does this not inherit the equals and hashcode methods of its parent. Or would it be a better design to implement my 'key_index' as its own true object, as you have done. PS I wish I could throw together code that quickly.