# where to initiate object in java

Tags: java, while-loop

This question relates to my answer of another of my question.
The original question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241215/using-hashmapstring-string-as-a-key-object-in-my-hashmapk-v/11242397#11242397)

Can anyone explain why the bad code fails in the way explained in the comments (by the wy it is in pseudo code)

```
 // bad code
        ResultSet rs = getDataFromDBMS("Select * from [tableName];");

            //temp uses a collection member within it to hold a list of column names to data value pairs (hashmap<String,String>)
        Object temp = new objectToHoldInfoFromResultSet();

        // loop over the result set
        while (rs.next)// for each row in the result set
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= rs.getNumberColums; i++) {
                temp.add(infoAboutColumn);
            }
            temp.printInfo();// always prints correct (ie current) info
                    //the print just takes the hashmap member and asks for a       
                    //toString() on it
            anotherObject(makeUseOf(temp));// always uses info from first
                   //iteration. Essentially grabs the hashMap member of temp, and puts
                   //this into another collection of type 
                   //HashMap< HashMap<String,String>, temp> see the linked question
                   //for more detail.

        }

        // Seemingly each loop into the while the temp.doSomethingToData(); uses
        // the temp object created in the first iteration

        // good code
        ResultSet rs = getDataFromDBMS("Select * from [tableName];");

        // loop over the result set
        while (rs.next)// for each row in the result set
        {
            Object temp = new objectToHoldInfoFromResultSet();// moving
                                                                // declaration
                                                                // of temp into
                                                                // the while
                                                                // loop solves
                                                                // the problem.
            for (int i = 1; i <= rs.getNumberColums; i++) {
                temp.add(infoAboutColumn);
            }
            temp.printInfo();// always prints correct (ie current) info

            anotherObject(makeUseOf(temp));// also uses the correct (ie current)
                                            // info.

        }
```

Comment: Well, what problem are you facing here?

Comment: dude. do we have to find the question and solve the answer ??

Comment: Put the entire question here and don't send us to the answers of another question please.

Comment: The code you have posted has many deficiencies, the worst arguably being that it is not valid Java. You are burdening those who want to help you with tasks that are the responsibility of you as the asker.

Comment: I apreciate your comments, but seemingly Peter Torok below was able to understand my question, and supply an answer that I find satisfactory. @AkhilDev ha ha, indeed, I had an answer but it raised a new question, so I clipped my answer for brevity. Marko Topolnik: Sorry I should probably have said I was supplying 'pseudo code', and I never said anything about it being java, except for the tag, as I knew the code wasn't good java

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: is the question any better now that I've edited the 'comments' in the code? what else can do I need to do to improve it?

Comment: Making it at least syntactically correct Java and respect Java naming conventions would help a lot. But, since you already have your answer, take this as advice for your future interactions on SO. Now it's just a waste of my time and yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't reliably answer this without knowing what `temp.printInfo()` and `makeUseOf()` are doing. It is easy to implement them to behave the way you describe though.

When you instantiate `temp` outside the loop, you will be using the same object throughout all iterations of the loop. Thus it is possible for it to gather data from each iteration (e.g. into a collection). And then it is possible for methods to get data accumulated in the current iteration, as well as from any previous iteration, which may cause problems if it was not intended.

So let's assume `temp` contains a collection and in each iteration a column from the resultset is added to it. Now if `temp.printInfo()` is implemented to print info about the *last* element in this collection, while `makeUseOf()` is implemented to do something with the *first* element in the collection, you get the behaviour you observed.

OTOH when you instantiate `temp` inside the loop, you will get a new, distinct object in each iteration, which won't "remember" any data from earlier iterations. Thus even with the implementations of `temp.printInfo()` and `makeUseOf()` outlined above, you will get correct results.

Comment: when I pass my temp object with anotherObjectMakeUseOf(temp) I don't specify anything about the info, so I assume it is highly likely it just pully the first object it finds. I'm going to accept your answer, as it reasonably explains the observed behaviour (even though this behaviour wasn't specificaly implemented). Thanks for taking the extra time to see your way through my 'defficient question' (hence the +1) David

Comment: further investigation makes me realise that is exactly what was happening. I was getting one member from the temp object programatically, but I guess the compiler recognised it as being the 'same object' and so copied a reference of it into the value slot relating to the derived key info, does that sound likely?

Comment: @DaveM, I don't think the (Java) compiler is doing such optimizations - the JIT *might* do something like that, but only after the code has been run a *lot* of times. But if it is the same parent object, and the member in question is not modified between calls, you get the same member object every time.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why the one is good and the other bad.  My guess (without knowing what objectToHoldInfoFromResultSet and the other methods behaviour are) is the following:

In the first instance, the "objectToHoldInfoFromResultSet" (should be capitalised) is created once and everytime

```
temp.add(infoAboutColumn);
```

is called, new record data is added to the object.  I would guess that this info should be cleared for each record... otherwise you'll get a lot of duplication.  The duplication is taken care of by re-initialising the holder object.  I.e. (1 2 3 4 5 6) instead of the (1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 6).

Without knowing more about the various propriety objects, there is not much more I can tell you.

Comment: I had kind of expected that the temp object would have the new data just overwrite the old info. but seemingly not, yours and peters answers are perfect, so thanks for taking the time (+1 for struggling your way through my deficient question